# Flutter - How do I make a widget inside scrollwidget unscrollable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The Code is confidential so I cant show much but I'll demostrate with an example here:

```
ExpendedPanel(
  expanded: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text()
            ]
          )
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

I have this Expanded panel that expands when clicked, with data on the panel, I want to add a button on the left side of the row that stays unscrollable even if I scroll the data left and right like below: (See the tick button next to the account name? I want the button to not scroll along if I scroll the account name part)

[image]

Failed attempts:

- Tried to add Stack insdie the singleChildScrollView and outside of it: hasSize() error.
- Tried to put it as a child of a parent row (row -> button, Scroll), cannot scroll, gets overriden by the expandable's slide feature.

Comment: add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` in `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change SingleChildScrollView(Row to

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children:[

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the scrollphysics of any scrollable widget to never scroll physics
and your widget is now not scrollable ..

hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

use `ListView` instead of `Row`

```
    ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: <Widget> [
       // your widgets
])
```